# what does print for mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

I need to edit some Perl script and I'm new to this language.
I encountered the following statement:

```
print for (@$result);
```

I know that **$result** is a reference to an array and **@$result** returns the whole array.
But what does **print for** mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [statement modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers)

Comment: Also note, this could've just been written as `print @$result;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to `for (@$result) { print; }`, which is equivalent to `for (@$result) { print $_; }`. `$_` refers to the current element.

Comment: thanks!! Ok one more small thing then.
Is the following equivalent to it then?
for $row(@$result) { print $row;}

Comment: Only if `$row` isn't in scope yet (in which case you should use `my $row`). If `$row` is in scope, it will be overwritten unless you shadow it with `my`.

Comment: @Ameen, In other words, if you do `for $var (...) { ... }`, you surely meant to do `for my $var (...) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, there's such a thing as an implicit variable. You may have seen it already as `$_`. There's a lot of built in functions in perl that will work on `$_` by default.

`$_` is set in a variety of places, such as loops. So you can do:

```
while ( <$filehandle> ) {
    chomp;
    tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    s/oldword/newword/;
    print;
}
```

Each of these lines is using `$_` and modifying it as it goes. Your `for` loop is doing the same - each iteration of the loop sets `$_` to the current value and `print` is then doing that by default.

I would point out though - whilst useful and clever, it's also a really good way to make confusing and inscrutable code. In nested loops, for example, it can be quite unclear what's actually going on with `$_`.

So I'd typically:

- avoid writing it explicitly - if you need to do that, you should consider actually naming your variable properly.
- only use it in places where it makes it clearer what's going on. As a rule of thumb - if you use it more than twice, you should *probably*  use a named variable instead.

I find it particularly useful if iterating on a file handle. E.g.:

```
while ( <$filehandle> ) {
   next unless m/keyword/; #skips any line without 'keyword' in it. 
   my ( $wiggle, $wobble, $fronk ) = split ( /:/ ); #split $_ into 3 variables on ':'
   print $wobble, "\n";
}
```

It would be redundant to assign a variable name to capture a line from `<$filehandle>`, only to immediately discard it - thus instead we use `split` which by default uses `$_` to extract 3 values.

If it's hard to figure out what's going on, then one of the more useful ways is to use `perl -MO=Deparse` which'll re-print the 'parsed' version of the script. So in the example you give:

```
foreach $_ (@$result) {
    print $_;
}
```